# How to store object-based data in a database so it remains queryable?

Tags: php, database, oop, object

I am constructing a PHP framework from scratch (unfortunately I don't have any choice in this matter). The framework is required to rely heavily on object-oriented data, and therefore needs to have the ability to store large amounts of object-oriented data efficiently.

I am struggling with the second part.

I've been working on this for a few months. Initially I was introduced to the idea of an ORM, after trying a few pre-built libraries (Doctrine 2, Redbean etc) I liked the idea, but none of what I could find functioned the way that was required, so I set out to create my own ORM, of which turned out quite well. The only issue really is that it suffers in performance, and after spending some time trying to optimize it, I am now convinced that an ORM is not quite the solution to the problem. Although close, it just doesn't quite cut it.

I have briefly looked into other solutions, but due to my lack of experience in this area I am struggling to pin-point the solution.

Here are the requirements of the data storage engine:

- Ultimately, it needs to be able to store key-value pairs
- The "value" part can be a simple data type, but can also be an object, or an array of the same type of object.
- The application defines the structure of each object (or the SCHEMA), sort of in the same way that a .wsdl file works, so the engine would need to like strict formats.
- Objects can either have their instances re-used, or not. Meaning that if an object exists as a child object in multiple locations (across many objects) its values are the same everywhere that it is located (if it re-used). Otherwise, a new instance of the object exists for every existing object (not re-used).
- There needs to be the ability to query the data efficiently, to make comparisons on any part of an object to find it. For example: `find a customer where customer.address.postcode LIKE ('%XXX%')`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Thanks to those that have attempted to aid me so far in my somewhat crazy endeavour. To answer some questions that have so far been asked:

*What solutions have you tried, and why did they not work?*

**ORM systems**

I had tried a small number of pre-built ORM libraries for PHP. Including Doctrine 2 and Redbean. With Doctrine it was more to do with how you specified the SCHEMA of a model, in that you are required to do so in docblocks. I found this particularly awkward to use due to the requirements that I had, particularly because I knew of a number of ways this could be avoided. I did eventually manage to get Doctrine to work the way that I wanted, but this was after hacking away at the code. Again, this was fun, but it wasn't right.

Redbean actively required me to change the property names of objects. One of my requirements was to basically be able to plug in any sort of document-oriented object, and store it. So having to specifically name properties in order to do this was counter-intuitive. Again, I did play with Redbean for a bit to get it to work, which wasn't right.

It was after playing with a few more ORM systems that I felt I had the knowledge to make my own. Again, the ORM system that I made was good, in that it met the requirements precisely. It was massively let-down due to poor performance, specifically when dealing with large sets of data, but more so when dealing with largely complex models.

**Storing objects in XML files**

There was a very small time that I considered this, thinking that maybe my requirements meant that I was always going to end up with performance being a problem. So I set out designing a way to generate text-based storage and ultimately ended up creating a whole SCHEMA engine and a bunch of other interesting things. This turned out to be just a fun project in the end, I just couldn't get it to perform at all.

**NoSQL**

My most recent endeavours have pushed me down the route of systems such as MongoDB and a few other NoSQL systems that I didn't much get into like Cassandra.

MongoDB comes very close to being a tool I *could* use, however it would require that I add an additional layer because I do in-fact require a SCHEMA, since my objects always conform to a specific structure. I am slowly coming to terms with MongoDB possibly being the solution, however I want to make sure before I spend more time on this.

*What exactly do you mean by efficient?*

I'm not 100% talking about performance when I mention efficiency, although performance is most certainly an important factor that I am using to consider my options, I understand that going down this route rather than something like a relational database, performance is naturally going to be a problem.

I am more talking about using the right tools. I never like to have to hack away at someone's code to get things to work. To me, it feels as if I am pushing things down a road that the system wasn't designed to go down, and at some point in the future it will bite me in the a**.

So really, when I mention I am looking for something "efficient", I'm meaning tools that match the requirements as closely as possible, so that I am only using/extending the functionality, rather than re-writing it.

Comment: It sounds like a nightmare. I'd recommend saying that you can't do it and move on to another project. Seems silly to build something from scratch that has been done many times by large teams of highly skilled engineers.

Comment: @gnarly I agree to an extent, but I have not been able to find an example of this being done. At least not in the way I have described. If you could point me to some examples that would be great

Comment: I would use Doctrine, you say that it doesn't meet your needs, but maybe the requirements could be changed to work with existing technology. It's the balance between spending thousands of hours building something yourself or making a compromise to avoid that heavy lift.

Comment: This requirement is the 'fun part': 'There needs to be the ability to query the data efficiently' - see: 'any of the big players'. Whatever, you need to define  'efficiently'. What have you looked at? Why did you reject them?

Comment: I actually spent quite a bit of time with Doctrine. Although I did enjoy using it, it was added to the list of tools that didn't quite fit the niche. An actual database solution would be closer to what I need, like MongoDB for example...

Comment: @RyanVincent - Some great questions. I will edit my post in attempt to answer those questions

Comment: How much data are your talking about? Estimates of number of records? Volumes? Number of Keys? Number of relations between the different data? How quickly you need to access it? You data structure currently? What it doesn't work with that you want it to.

Comment: @RyanVincent in fear of extending this post to crazy lengths, i'll let you respond before I answer any more questions. Please do let me know if there is any more information I can give

Comment: I have extended my question into another post which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501791/discovering-the-best-approach-to-storing-a-specific-object-oriented-data-structu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some routes to look into. Your requirement for storing "objects" (quite a broad term when it comes to databases) makes me think of:

- Storing data in databases in a serialised format, e.g. JSON. PostgreSQL these days [has ways to reach into such a column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to do search operations on it, so it is not as non-searchable as has been previously regarded (though I would expect it to be slower than querying correctly normalised data).
- The requirement to store `customer.address.postcode` makes me think that you could store your data as a hierarchy, in which case there are several algorithms available to you. Look into [nested sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). This is designed to work well with relational databases, without resorting to recursive SQL.
- It's not an area of my expertise, but [graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) may be worth looking into.

On a side note, Doctrine is a great library from what I hear, but I suspect you need to work out what technology to use first. It is designed broadly to map onto a relational database, so if you can't express your problem cleanly in a raw RDBMS, Doctrine may not help.

(This could be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/), it's hard to tell. You've said you need Y, but if you can tell us that you want to achieve X, maybe the feedback you're getting would be more concrete - and take you in a better direction).

Comment: Your first point is another technique that I had tried some time ago. Your concerns are in the right place with that in terms of performance.

I have to thank you though. I wasn't aware of nested sets, which appears to exactly what I am looking for! So thank you very much for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: Great, @Donny! Propel and Doctrine both have nested set implementations, you could look into them. From what I recall the Propel one is really easy to use (not tried the Doctrine one, should also be straightforward).

Comment: I'll have a look at Propel too. Looking into nested sets brought me to graph databases also which looks like another potential solution

Comment: Ha, yes I wondered if I should mention graph databases - never tried one though.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure. Graph databases *look* like they closer suit my needs but i'm already noticing that it seems to create more problems to resolve. I think I may well be destined to creating a custom ORM, however I am going to make one last attempt and extend this question into another post that will outline exactly what it is that I am trying to do. For those interested, please stay tuned!