# Discovering the best approach to storing a specific object-oriented data structure

Tags: php, database, oop, object

After some fantastic suggestions, and a sleepless night of excitement due to the possibility of finally having a solution to my problem, I realize that I'm still not quite at a solution. So, I am here to outline my problem in much more detail in hope that someone knows of the best way to achieve this.

To recap (if you haven't read [the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482648/how-to-store-object-based-data-in-a-database-so-it-remains-queryable)):

- I am constructing a PHP OOP framework from scratch (I have no choice in this matter)
- The framework is required to handle object-oriented data in the most efficient way possible. It doesn't need to be lightning quick, it just needs to be the best possible solution to the problem
- Objects very closely resemble strictly written oop objects, in that they are an instance of a specific class, which contains a strict set of properties.
- Object properties can be basic types (strings, numbers, bools) but can also be one object instance, or an array of objects (with the restriction that the array must be objects of the same type)

Ultimately, a storage engine that supports document-oriented storage (similar to XML or JSON) where the objects themselves have a strict structure.

Instead of outlining what I have tried so far (I discussed this briefly in my previous post) I am going to spend the rest of this post explaining, in detail, what it is that I am trying to do. This post is going to be long (sorry!).

---

To get started, I need to discuss a terminology that I had to introduce to solve one of the most crucial problems that came with the set of requirements. I've named this terminology **"persistence"**. I understand that this term does have a different meaning when dealing with object databases, and for this reason I am open to suggestions on a different term. But for now, let's move on.

**Persistence**

Persistence refers to the independence of an object. I found the need to introduce this terminology when considering the data structure being generated from XML (which is something that I had to be able to do). In XML, we see objects that are completely dependent on their parent, while we also see objects that can be independent of a parent object.

The below example is an example of an XML document, that conforms to a certain structure (for example, a .wsdl file). Each object resembles a type with a strict structure. **Every object has an "id" property**

[image: data example xml]

In the above example, we see two users. Both have their own Address objects under their "address" property. However if we look at their "favouriteBook" property, we can see that they both **re-use** the same Book object instance. Also note that the books use the same author.

So we have the Address object which is **non-persistent** because it is only related to its parent object (the User) meaning that its instance only needs to exist while the owning User object exists. Then the Book object which is **persistent** because it can be used in multiple locations and its instance remains persistent.

At first, I felt a bit crazy for coming up with a terminology like this, however, I found it remarkably simple to understand and use practically. It ultimately condenses the the "many-to-many, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one" formula into a simple idea that I felt worked much better with nested data.

I've made an image representation of the above data here:

[image: Data connections diagram]

With my definition of persistence, comes a set of rules to help in understanding it. These rules are as follows:

- **update/create**
- Persistent child objects of the base object being stored **update** the properties of the persistent object, ultimately updating its instance.
- Non-persistent objects **always** create a new instance of the object to ensure that they always use a non-persistent instance (no two non-persistent instances exist in more than one place at any given time)
- **deleting**
- Persistent child objects of the base object do not get deleted recursively. This is because the persistent object may exist in other places. You would always delete a persistent object directly.
- Non-persistent child objects of the base object are removed along with the base object. If they were not removed, they would be left stranded as their design requires that the have a parent.
- **retrieving**
- Since persistent mostly defines how modifications work, retrieval doesn't involve persistence a great deal, aside from how you would expect persistence to effect how a model is stored and therefore how it would be retrieved (persistent object instances remaining persistent wherever it is located, non-persistent objects always having their own instance)

One final thing to note before we move on - the persistence of data models is defined by the model itself **rather than the relationship**. Initially, the persistence was part of the relationship but this was completely unnecessary when the system expects that you know the structure of your models, and how they are used. Ultimately, every model instance of a model is either persistent, or it is not.

---

So taking a look at some code now, you might start to see the method behind the madness. Although it may seem that the reason for this solution is to be able to build a storage system around objective data conforming to set of conditions, it's design actually comes from wanting to be able to store class instances, and/or generate class instances from an objective data structure.

I have written some pseudo-classes as an example of the functionality that I am trying to produce. I have commented most methods, including type declarations.

So first, this would be the base class that all model classes would extend. The purpose of this class is to create a layer between the model class/object, and the database/storage engine:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the base class that all models would extend. It contains the functionalities that are useful among all model
 * objects, such as crud actions, finding, and crud event management.
 *
 * @author Donny Sutherland <donny@pixelpug.co.uk>
 * @package Main
 * @subpackage Sub
 *
 * Class ORMModel
 */
class ORMModel {
    /**
     * In order to generate relationships between objects, every object MUST have an id. This functions as the object's
     * unique identifier. Each object in it's model type (collection) has it's own id.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * Internal property assigned by the application. This is where the persistence of the model is defined.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $internal_isPersistent = true;
    /**
     * Internal property assigned by the application. This is an array of the model's properties, and their PHP type.
     *
     * For example, a User model might use something like this:
     * array(
        "id" => "integer",
     *  "username" => "string",
     *  "password" => "string",
     *  "address" => "object",
     *  "favouriteBook" => "object",
     *  "allBooks" => "array"
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $internal_propertyTypes = array();
    /**
     * Internal property assigned by the application. This is an array of the model's properties which are objects, and
     * the MODEL CLASS type of the object.
     *
     * For example, the User model example for the property types might use this:
     * array(
     *  "address" => "Address",
        "favouriteBook" => "Book",
     *  "allBooks" => "Book"
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $internal_objectTypes = array();
    /**
     * I am not 100% sure on the best way to use this yet, I have tried a few different ways and all seem to cause
     * performance problems. But ultimately, before we attempt to update an object, we cache it's currently stored
     * instance to this property, allowing us to compare old vs new. I find this really useful for detecting whether a
     * property has changed, I just need to work out the best way to do it.
     *
     * @var $this
     */
    protected $internal_old;

    /**
     * The lazy way to construct an empty model object (all NULL values)
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function constructEmpty() {

    }

    /**
     * This method is used by the other constructFromXXX methods once the data has been converted to a PHP array.
     * This method is what allows us to build a RESTful interface into the ORM system as it conforms to the following
     * rules:
     *
     * - if the id is set (not null), first pull the object from storage.
     * - For each key => value of the passed array, OVERWRITE the value
     * - For properties that are model objects/arrays, if the property is assiged to the array:
     *  - if the array value is NULL, we are clearing the object relationship
     *  - if the array valus is not null, construct recursively at this point
     *
     * Ultimately, if you assign a property in the array that you pass to this method, it will overwrite the value. If
     * you do not, it will use the property value in storage.
     *
     * @param array $array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function constructFromArray(array $array) {

    }

    /**
     * This method attempts to decode the value of $json into a PHP array. It then calls constructFromArray if the string
     * could be decoded.
     *
     * @param $json
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function constructFromJson($json) {

    }

    /**
     * This method attempts to decode the value of $xml into a PHP array. It then calls constructFromArray if the xml
     * could be decoded.
     *
     * @param $xml
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function constructFromXml($xml) {

    }

    /**
     * Find one object, based on a set of options.
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function findOne(ORMCrudOptions $options) {

    }

    /**
     * Find all objects, (optionally) based on a set of options
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return $this[]
     */
    final public static function findAll(ORMCrudOptions $options=null) {

    }

    /**
     * Find the count of objects, based on a set of optoins
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    final public static function findCount(ORMCrudOptions $options) {

    }

    /**
     * Find one object, based on it's id, and (optionally) a set of options.
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    final public static function findById($id,ORMCrudOptions $options=null) {

    }

    /**
     * Push this object to storage. This creates/updates all of the contained objects, based on their id's and
     * persistence.
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function pushThis(ORMCrudOptions $options) {

    }

    /**
     * Pull this object form storage. This retrieves all of the contained objects again, based on their id's and
     * persistence.
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function pullThis(ORMCrudOptions $options) {

    }

    /**
     * Remove this object from storage. This conditionally removes the contained objects (based on persistence) based
     * on their id's.
     *
     * @param ORMCrudOptions $options
     */
    final public function removeThis(ORMCrudOptions $options) {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function beforeCreate() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function afterCreate() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function beforeUpdate() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function afterUpdate() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function beforeRemove() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function afterRemove() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function beforeRetrieve() {

    }

    /**
     * This is a crud event.
     */
    public function afterRetrieve() {

    }
}
```

So ultimately, this class would be designed to provide the functionality to construct, find, save, retrieve and delete model objects. The internal properties are properties that exist only in the classes (not in storage). These properties get populated by the framework itself while you use an interface to create models, and add property/fields to the models.

The idea is, the framework comes with an interface for managing data models. With this interface you create the models, and add property/fields to the models. In doing so, the system automatically creates the class files for you, updating those internal properties as you modify the persistence and property types.

To keep things developer friendly, the system creates two class files for each model. A base class (which extends ORMModel) and another class (which extends the base class). The base class is manipulated by the system and therefore modifying this file is not recommended. The other class is used by developers to add additional functionality to models and crud events.

So coming back to the example data, here is the User base class:

```
    <?php
class User_Base extends ORMModel {
    public $name;
    public $pass;
    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    public $address;
    /**
     * @var Book
     */
    public $favouriteBook;

    protected $internal_isPersistent = true;
    protected $internal_propertyTypes = array(
        "id" => "integer",
        "name" => "string",
        "pass" => "string",
        "address" => "object",
        "favouriteBook" => "object"
    );
    protected $internal_objectTypes = array(
        "address" => "Address",
        "favouriteBook" => "Book"
    );
}
```

Pretty much self explanatory. Again note that the internal properties get generated by the system, so those arrays would be generated based on the property/fields that you specify when creating/modifying the User model in the model management interface. Also note the docblock on the address and `favouriteBook` property definitions. Those are also generated by the system making the classes very IDE friendly.

This would be the other class generated for the User model:

```
    <?php
final class User extends User_Base {
    public function beforeCreate() {

    }

    public function afterCreate() {

    }

    public function beforeUpdate() {

    }

    public function afterUpdate() {

    }

    public function beforeRemove() {

    }

    public function afterRemove() {

    }

    public function beforeRetrieve() {

    }

    public function afterRetrieve() {

    }
}
```

Again, pretty self explanatory. We've extended the base class to create another class where developers would add additional methods, and add functionality to the crud events.

I'll not add in the other objects that make up the rest of the example data. Since the above should explain how they would look.

So you may/may not have noticed that in the ORMModel class, the CRUD methods require an instance of an ORMCrudOptions class. This class is pretty crucial to the whole system, so lets take a quick look at that:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Despite this object being some-what aggregate, it it quite possibly the most important part of the ORM, in that it
 * defines how CRUD actions are executed, and outline how the querying is done.
 *
 * Class ORMCrudOptions
 */
final class ORMCrudOptions {
    /**
     * This ultimately makes up the "where" part of the sql query. However, because we want to be able to make querying
     * possible at any depth within the hierarchy of a model, this gets quite complicated.
     *
     * Previously, I developed a system which allowed the user to do something like this:
     *
     * "this.customer.address.postcode LIKE ('%XXX%') OR this.customer.address.line1 LIKE ('%XXX%')
     *
     * he "this" and the "." are my extension to basic sql. The "this" refers to the base model that you are finding,
     * and each "." basically drills down into the hierarchy to make a comparison on a property somewhere within a
     * contained model object.
     *
     * I will explain more how I did this in my post, I am most definitely looking at how I could better achieve this
     * though.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $query;
    /**
     * This allows you to build up a list of order by definitions.
     *
     * Using the orderBy method, you can chain up the order by statements like:
     *
     * ->orderBy("this.name","asc")->orderBy("this.customer.address.line1","desc")
     *
     * Which would be similar to doing:
     *
     * ORDER BY this_name ASC, this_customer_address.line1 DESC
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $orderBy;
    /**
     * This allows you to set the limit start and limit values by doing:
     *
     * ->limit(10,10)
     *
     * Which would be similar to doing:
     *
     * LIMIT 10, 10
     *
     * @var
     */
    private $limit;
    /**
     * Depth was added in my later en devours to try and help with performance. It allows you to specify the depth at
     * which to retrieve data. Although this helped with optimisation a lot, I really disliked having to use
     * implement this because it seems like a work-around. I would rather be able to increase performance elsewhere so
     * that objects are always retrieved at their full depth
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $depth;
    /**
     * This was another newly added feature. Whenever you execute a crud action on a model, the model instance is stored
     * in a local cache if this is true, and/or retrieved from this cached if this value is true.
     *
     * I did find this to make a significant increase on performance, although it did bring in complications that make
     * the system tricky to use at times. You really need to understand how and when to use the cache, otherwise it can
     * be infuriatingly obtuse.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $useCache;
    /**
     * Built into the ORM system, and tied in with the application I set up a webhook system which fires out webhooks on
     * crud events. I discovered the need to be able to disable webhooks at times (when doing large amounts of crud
     * actions in one go) pretty early on. Setting this to false basically disables webhooks on the crud action
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $fireWebhooks;
    /**
     * Also build into the application, and tied into the ORM system is an access system. This works on a seperate
     * layer to the database, allowing me to use the same access system as I use for everything in the framework as I do
     * for defining crud action access. However, in some instances I found it useful to disable access checks.
     *
     * This is always on by default. In the api system that I built to access the data models, you were not able to
     * modify this property and therefore were always subject to access checks.
     *
     * @var
     */
    private $ignoreAccessChecks;

    /**
     * The lazy way to create a new instance of options.
     *
     * @return ORMCrudOptions
     */
    public static function n() {
        return new ORMCrudOptions();
    }

    /**
     * Set the query value
     *
     * @param $query
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function query($query) {
        $this->query = $query;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add an orderby field and direction
     *
     * @param $field
     * @param string $direction
     *
     * @return $this
     * @internal param array $orderBy
     *
     */
    public function orderBy($field,$direction="asc") {
        $this->orderBy[] = array($field,$direction);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the limit start and limit.
     *
     * @param $limitResults
     * @param null $limitStart
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function limit($limitResults,$limitStart=null) {
        $this->limit = array($limitResults,$limitStart);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the depth for retrieval
     *
     * @param $depth
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function depth($depth) {
        $this->depth = $depth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether to use the model cache
     *
     * @param $useCache
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function useCache($useCache) {
        $this->useCache = $useCache;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether to fire webhooks on crud actions
     *
     * @param $fireWebhooks
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fireWebhooks($fireWebhooks) {
        $this->fireWebhooks = $fireWebhooks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether to ignore access checks
     *
     * @param $ignoreAccessChecks
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function ignoreAccessChecks($ignoreAccessChecks) {
        $this->ignoreAccessChecks = $ignoreAccessChecks;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The idea behind this class is to remove the need to have a large number of arguments in the crud methods, and because the majority of those arguments can be re-used in all of the crud methods. Take note of the comments on the query property, as that is one is important.

---

So, that pretty much covers the base psuedo-code and ideas behind what it is that I am trying to do. So finally, I'll show some user-scenarios:

```
<?php
//the most simple way to store a user
$user = User::constructEmpty();
//we use auto incrementing on the id value at the database end. So by not specifying the id, we are not updaing, and
//the id will be auto generated. After the push has been made, the system will assign the id for me
$user->name = "bob";
$user->pass = "bobpass";
//the system automatically constructs child objects for you if they are not yet constructed, because
//it knows what type should be constructed. So I don't need to construct the address object, manually!
$user->address->line1 = "awesome drive";
$user->address->zip = "90051";
//save to storage, but don't fire webhooks and ignore access checks. Note that the ORMCrudOptions object
//is passed to child objects too when recursion happens, meaning that the same options are inherited by child objects
$user->pushThis(ORMCrudOptions::n()->fireWebhooks(false)->ignoreAccessChecks(true));
echo $user->id; //this will display the auto generated id
echo $user->address->id; //this will be the audo generated id of the address object.

//next lets update something within the object
$user->name = "bob updated";
//because we know now that the object has an id value, it will update the existing object. Remembering tha the User
//object is persistent!
$user->pushThis(ORMCrudOptions::n()->fireWebhooks(false)->ignoreAccessChecks(true));
echo $user->id; //this will be the exact same id as before
echo $user->address->id; //this will be a NEW ID! Remember, the address object is NOT persistent meaning that a new
//instance was created in order to ensure that is is infact non-persistent. The system does handle cleaning up of loose
//objects although this is one of the main perforance problems

//finding the above object by user->name
$user = User::findOne(ORMCrudOptions::n()->query("this.name = ('bob')"));
if($user) {
    echo $user->name; //provided that a user with name "bob" exsists, this would output "bob"
}

//finding the above user by address->zip
$user = User::findOne(ORMCrudOptions::n()->query("this.address.zip = ('90051')"));
if($user) {
    echo $user->address->zip; //provided that the user with address->zip "90051" exists, this would output "90051"
}

//removing the above user
$user = User::findById(1); //assuming that the id of the user id 1
//add a favourite book to the user
$user->favouriteBook->name = "awesome book!";
//update
$user->pushThis(ORMCrudOptions::n()->ignoreAccessChecks(true));
//remove
$user->removeThis(ORMCrudOptions::n()->ignoreAccessChecks(true));
//with how persistence works, this will delete the user, and the user's address (because the address is non-persistence)
//but will leave the created book un-deleted, because books are persistent and may exist as child objects to other objects

//finally, constructing from document-oriented
$user = User::constructFromArray(array(
    "user" => "bob",
    "pass" => "passbob",
    "address" => array(
        "line1" => "awesome drive",
        "zip" => "90051"
    )
));
//this will only CONSTRUCT the object based on the internal properties defined property types and object types.
//properties that don't exist in the model's defined properties, but exist in the array will be ignored, so having more
//properties in the array than should be there doesn't matter
$user->pushThis(ORMCrudOptions::n()->ignoreAccessChecks(true));

//update only one property of a user object using arrays (this is ultimately how the api system of the ORM was built)
$user = User::constructFromArray(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "user" => "bob updated"
));
echo $user->pass; //this would output passbob, because the pass was not specified in the array, it was pulled form storage
```

It's not really possible to show here, but one of the things that makes this system a delight to use is how the the generation of the class files makes them incredibly IDE friendly (in particular, for auto-completion). Yeah, some of the old-school developers will be against this new-modern-fangled-technology, but at the end of the day when you are dealing with crazily complex object-oriented data structures, having the IDE help you in spelling your property names correctly and getting the structure correct can be a life-saver!

If you are still with me, thank you for reading. You are probably wondering though, *what is it you want again?*.

In short, I don't have a huge amount of experience in document/object storage and already in the past few days I've been shown that there are technologies out there that could help my achieve what it is that I am trying to do. I'm just not 100% certain yet that I have found the right one. Do I create a new ORM, can I efficiently get this functionality out of an existing ORM, do I use a dedicated object/graph database?

I very much welcome any and all suggestions!

Comment: This is an extension of my old post, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482648/how-to-store-object-based-data-in-a-database-so-it-remains-queryable

Comment: Please be more succinct. Or at the very least put a summary, of the main points, at the top of the question.

Comment: My initial response is that "persistence" is the wrong term here, since it is already taken - it means, essentially, to store something. It can be a bit confusing to need to remember that it means something different, especially in the context of a storage system! Not to worry though, I think I can work around that. My nested set idea on the previous question still stands, I'll add some extra detail to that in a bit.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I can't help but feel that I have done this already? Could you give me more detail on how you suggest that I improve the post? Many thanks

Comment: @halfer - Yeah I very much expect that to be the case and am gearing towards thinking up a new term for it, "independance" seems to make sense also. Definitely looking forward to seeing what you can come up with! Thanks again for the pointers

Comment: (We tend to eschew external links here, especially file locker sites, since they are quite brittle, and if they break, future interested readers may not follow the question. I tried to move the XML sample into your post, but it exceeded the maximum 30K post length - not something I have seen before! Can some of the comments from `ORMCrudOptions` be excised?)

Comment: @halfer - understandable. I was really struggling with the 3k limit! I had to actually provide links intstead of including files in the content, however I am also currently limited to 2 links per post. I'll go over the post to see if I can fit the xml file content in. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still feels like this is a nested set algorithm, because your data will always fit into a hierarchy. Simple types (strings, integers, etc) have a hierarchy of depth 1, and an object expression like `customer.address.postcode` (from your related post) will have a hierarchy level for each component (3 in this case, with the corresponding string value stored in the outermost node).

It seems that this hierarchy can store different types, so you'd need to make a small change to the nested set algorithm. Rather than each node carrying class-specific (Address, User, etc) columns, you have a string reference to the type and an integer primary key to reference it. This means that you can't use foreign key constraints for this part of your database, but that's a small price to pay. (The reason for this is a single column cannot obey one of several constraints, it would have to obey them all. That said, you could probably do something clever with a pre-insert/pre-update trigger though).

So, if you were to use a Doctrine or Propel NestedSet behaviour, you would define tables thus:

- Node

  - [nested set columns, done for you in an ORM]
  - `name` (varchar, records the element name e.g. `customer`)
  - `is_persistent` (bool)
  - `table_name` (varchar)
  - `primary_key` (integer)
- Address

  - (Your usual columns, ditto any other table)

Now, we have an interesting property emerging here: when creating a hierarchy, you'll see that the trivial values in the leaf nodes can be shared by virtue of our reference system. In fact, I am not entirely sure the `is_persistent` boolean is required: it is persistent (if I have understood your term correctly) by virtue of sharing external table rows, and non-persistent if it does not.

So, if `customer1.address.postcode` has a particular string value, you can get `customer2.address.postcode` to point to the same thing. When updating the version pointed to by the first expression, the second one will update "automatically" (because it resolves to the same table row).

The advantage here is that this will bolt onto Propel and Doctrine without much work, and without any core hacking at all. You'd need to do some work to convert an object/array to a hierarchy, but that's probably not much code.

---

Addendum: let me explain my thinking a bit more in relation to the storage of nested elements. You say that you believe that you need to share a hierarchy at different levels in different places, but I am not so sure (and presently I think you need some encouragement not to build an excessively complicated system!). Let us look at an example, of a user having a favourite book.

To store it, we create these hierarchies:

```
user
node level 1
points to user record containing id=1, name=bob, pass=bobpass
    favouriteBook
    node level 2
    points to book record containing id=1, name=awesome book
        author
        node level 3
        points to author record containing id=3, name=peter, pass=peterpass
```

Now, let's say we have another user and want to share a different favourite book by the same author (i.e. we are sharing `user.favouriteBook.author`).

```
user
node level 1
points to different user record containing id=100, name=halfer, pass=halferpass
    favouriteBook
    node level 2
    points to different book record containing id=101, name=textbook
        author
        node level 3
        points to same author record (id = 3)
```

How about two users who share the same favourite book? No problem (we *additionally* share `user.favouriteBook`):

```
user
node level 1
points to different user record containing id=101, name=donny, pass=donnypass
    favouriteBook
    node level 2
    points to previous book record (id=1)
        author
        node level 3
        points to previous author record (id = 3)
```

One critique that could be made of this method is that if you make `user.favouriteBook` "persistent" (i.e. shared) then it should share `user.favouriteBook.author` automatically. This is because if two or more people like the same book, it will be by the same author(s) for all of them.

However, I noted in the comments why I think my explicit approach is better: the alternative might be a nested set of a nested set, which might get too complicated, and as yet I don't think you've demonstrated you need that. The trade-off is that my approach needs a bit more storage, but I think that's fine. You also have some more setting-up of objects, but if you have a single factory for this, and solidly unit test it, I don't think you need to worry.

(I think my approach could be faster too, but it is harder to say without developing a prototype for both and measuring performance on real datasets).

---

Addendum 2, to clean up some of the comments discussions and preserve it as an answer in the context of the question.

To determine whether the suggestion I outline here is feasible, you'll need to create a prototype. I would recommend using an existing nested set solution, such as Propel with the NestedSetBehaviour, though GitHub will have many other libraries you can try. Do not try to integrate this prototype into your own ORM at this stage, as the integration work will just be a distraction. At the moment you want to test the idea for feasibility, that's all.

Comment: As a quick response (before I look deeper into this), persistence is more to do with how an object is related to a parent object. In that it is either always linked to one parent (non-persistent), or it is linked to none/many (persistent). The best way to understand why this is useful is to look at what happens when objects are deleted/updated (defined in the persistence rules). Now, to get my head around your post! =]

Comment: OK @Donny. As I made that suggestion, I did wonder if the column is necessary - a node without a shared value may still need to be marked as persistent, even though presently it is not sharing anything.

Comment: Addendum: my approach outlined here will share non-compound types just fine, i.e. if you don't mind sharing `customer.address.postcode` and `customer.address.line1` separately. However with a bit of tweaking you could add another nested set so as to share `customer.address` and "inherit" all child nodes automatically. However, that might add too much complexity (nested sets that reference other nested sets start to reproduce the problems that recursive SQL try to solve, and we are trying deliberately to avoid that!). So stick with the simple version if you can.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial concern when i started looking into nested sets, in that no matter how I look at it, in wanting to be able to have re-use instances of objects in multiple locations across the data network at any given time, can I ever actually avoid recursion? Recursion is definitely the main cause of performance problems...

Comment: @Donny: In fact, my example above is misleading: my post shows how to share addresses already without any extra work. What I haven't show is how to share objects that have a depth of more than 1. If the depth _is_ 1, then of course it is just a row - and the external reference approach caters for that already. I would say that if you have deep objects that need to be shared, see if they can be broken down to shared rows instead.

Comment: `I would say that if you have deep objects that need to be shared, see if they can be broken down to shared rows instead` - objects can not only have more than one depth, but they can also exist, in multiple places, at multiple depths. So yeah, flexible depths are an absolute must. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "broken down to shared rows"? I'm not sure what you mean by this...

Comment: in-fact, an object instance, needs to be able to have multiple depths. It might exist in one hierarchy at depth 1, while it might exist in another object at depth 2. This could go on (technically an infinite number of times). This is only really a thing for persistent objects, since non-persistent instances can only exist in one place each. Does the nested set algorithm really support this?

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I really do appreciate your hard efforts! So, your addendum points towards nests not remaining intact (if I understand you correctly?). So if we imagine your "nodes" as physical/draggable elements, if I drag the book node onto a user's "favouriteBook" property, in theory you are saying that the link between the book and author would need to re-create itself because a nest doesn't remain intact automatically?

Comment: Correct @Donny. However, you shouldn't let the user do that: in your code, you can detect that a book has child nodes, and copy them at the same time as the top-most node. Don't forget that each node contains references to rows, not row data themselves, so they are fairly cheap to copy.

Comment: Hmm... there are too many scenarios where that would cause problems. For example, you *should* (with the way that document-oriented data works) be able to update the author's name by pushing the User object, and changing nothing but the user.favouriteBook.author.name. My way supports this, unfortunately your way would mean that every object is non-persistent (in a way) in that it is a "clone" of an instance (regardless of having the same id...), rather than theoretically being the same instance...

Comment: I don't think that critique is correct @Donny. If you change `user.favouriteBook.author.name` then that resolves to a column (`name`) in a single table (`author`) outside of the nested set, which is already shared. Certainly, modifying all users in a hierarchy would need multiple inserts (e.g. adding `user.favouriteLibrary.openingTimes` would require adding a `favouriteLibrary` child to every `user`, which in turn each point to a `Library` record) but that may well be acceptable performance-wise.

Comment: That has me a little more convinced then! I'm struggling a little to visualize some aspects of your idea though, most probably due to my lack of experience in this area. I wouldn't be able to grab some time with you on skype or something similar to go over some finer details? It would be much appreciated

Comment: Apologies for my delay in getting back to you. Yeah, being a developer that often helps out others myself I wouldn't be expecting much. I am really keen to trial out your idea in the attempt to find the reasoning behind it, I'm just struggling to wrap my head around the basis of it at the moment.

Comment: So, using propel: I know you are suggesting against it, however I just can't help but feel creating a custom ORM would tie in better with the framework as a whole, in that the ORM isn't designed to plug into any situation, but more-so just with the framework. Using another library, in my eyes, means a lot of guff I often don't need. With that being said, if I can understand your argument a bit more I might be swayed!

Comment: In terms of setting up a prototype, currently my framework+ORM are on version 4 (I am in the midst of refactoring for version 5, hence the need to revamp the data storage system) and currently version 4 is being used in a live-ish scenario, I would be very much up for showing you what i've done, in hope that we can locate the main issues and possibly compare against your suggestions. If you would be up for that, please do let me know!

Comment: by "version" I literally just mean iteration. In that, i've refactored the framework+ORM roughly 4 times now, and am about to move on to the 5th time. It might sound crazy, but I am a firm believer in the fact that there is always room for new tools that do things slightly differently. Haha, wow, another new term... NIH syndrome sounds like something I 100% am capable of, but again... if you've got the time and willingness to try, why not? With that being said, I am still 100% up for investigating your suggestion further as I do feel it is taking me down the right path.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck moving property this weekend. I'll set up a bitbucket (if you're okay with bitbucket?) on Monday of a live implementation of the framework+ORM and we can take it from there. Thanks a million for your advice so far man, it's been really helpful.

Comment: Until then, actually, you'll find the source files for the framework+ORM (non-implemented) here: https://bitbucket.org/donnysobonny/extorio-4/src

The ORM currently exists quite similarly to the class structure I displayed in my post. You'll find a set of Core_ORM_xxx classes in /core/classes. The basic model class is going to be removed in version 5 so i'd ignore that. You'll find the actual model classes in /core/models (the models that are built into the framework).

Comment: In all honesty man, i'd be up for spending as much time as is needed to build a prototype and unit tests and whatever else it is that you suggest to do. I've been desperate to find a better solution for a while so I'm definitely willing to do what it takes.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you possibly bullet-point what this nested set demo should aim to do, just so i've got a little bit of direction? Asside from that, no problem, and thanks again for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're a star. Thanks very much. Can you let me know the best way to get in touch? I imagine I should have something done by the end of next week

Comment: So i've been making a start at this nested set demo, and it's starting to make quite a bit of sense. I've got one issue though. The idea seems to revolve around knowing the base of the "node", as without it, the node and depth would be redundant... This could make this solution insanely complex because technically every level of the hierarchy could be a base, therefore every possible base would need to be recorded... is there a way this could be done without needing a base?

Comment: I think it might be that I am missing something... as I vaguely remember you talking about this already but here's my concern: http://pastie.org/9953482

Comment: @Donny, seems like you're focussing too much on "lefts and rights". That's just the implementation. Nested set works, there's no question about that, it records hierarchy very well indeed. Write a simple API so you can get _children_ instead, so you can add children and delete them. I'm a bit concerned that you appear to be writing this in the context of your ORM - I understand you want to integrate it, but the point of this prototype is a proof of concept. We don't know if it will work, and integration now will just be a distraction.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, yeah I was focused on implementation. So i've found a really simple nested set library for PHP and mysql. It's very buggy, which is actually proving to be a pretty good thing as it's helping me work out a little more how to actually implement nested sets. One additional question comes to mind though: You've mentioned that we are going to include a table name and primary key, to link to the row that the "node" is assigned to (i understand this now). However, how would we tie the "property" into this, is that to go into this table too? Also...

Comment: I can see, using this method, how we would very efficiently find hierarchies. It's performance so far is astounding in comparison to how I was doing it. I'm a little confused though, how we would also get the actual row data that the node is assigned to, in the same query and actually be able to use the results to construct the object... i'm seeing the word "recursion" again which is giving me the hee-bee-jee-bees!

Comment: "how would we tie the "property" into this, is that to go into this table too?" - I don't think it is necessary. You can detect if a request is made for `customer.address.postcode`, and if `postcode` has no children then do a check to see if the related table at the `address` node has a column called `postcode`. (This might have the consequence that you cannot have a naming conflict between columns and nodes at this level, but you might find a way around that).

Comment: "how we would also get the actual row data that the node is assigned to" - the node contains a reference to them, via the columns I've explained in my answer. No recursion.

Comment: Re the property idea. `customer.**address**.postcode`, the "**address**" part is the property name rather than the object type. A better example would be that **both** of these would point to an Address object: `customer.shippingAddress` and `customer.billingAddress`. I really love your idea to return row/object/objects based on the query string, but in our case, the join happens on the property like so `parent>property>child`. Rather than `parent>child`. I guess we're going to need to have the property in our main table that stores the nests...?

Comment: In addition to the above, `customer.shippingAddress` would be an invalid query string when you think about doing comparisons... considering you're going to want to be checking if customer.shippingAddress matches a condition, and matching objects in sql, I wouldn't even want to think what that would involve! So yeah, I think it would need to be a requirement that your query string fields lead to an actual property rather than an object. For example: `customer.shippingAddress.postcode` would be valid.

Comment: "the node contains a reference to them, via the columns I've explained in my answer" - this part I fully understand. The part I'm a bit unsure about (really, i've never actually done anything like this in SQL), is how I would actually get the results from different tables, and different rows, in a single query, considering obviously that tables will have their own unique field sets. Assigning the object row to the right property at the right level in the constructed object I am struggling with too, but I think i can work that one out...

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single query (or, if you can, it would be either too complicated or too slow to do so).

Comment: "A better example would be that both of these would point to an Address object: `customer.shippingAddress` and `customer.billingAddress`". Sure they can. If they both exist as separate hiearchies, they can both point to the same table/pk. (I'll now take a couple of days away from this question in order to help others, so if you can hack on it on your own for a while that would be great! Happy to help again, but probably not several times a day).

Comment: "I think it would need to be a requirement that your query string fields lead to an actual property rather than an object" - you can do that, but I don't see what benefit it obtains. Try both ways and see. My concern with this approach is your hierarchy table will have a lot more entries in it than it needs, and might become too slow. Still, you are right that some design trade-offs need to be made in general - maybe this is one of them. Happy hacking, for now!

Comment: (I forgot about the `name` component in the Node table above, will add that - kind of important for the design!)

Comment: No worries mate, you've been such a great help so far, your advice has been incredibly helpful. I'll take the information you've provided and see what I can come up with. I'm pretty sure I've got what I need to get something set up. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey bud, I've been working away at this nested set stuff over the past few days, and I've come to a stumbling block, and I'm completely stuck in coming up with a solution for it. Previously, we discovered that it wouldn't be possible to link the actual table's **row** to the node in the tree, which makes sense. But this poses a problem when it comes to actually trying to query the data. I've outlined the problem here, with some examples: http://pastie.org/9962144

Comment: How many instances of `base.shippingAddress.postcode` are possible, @Donny? I was working on the assumption that the tree expression is unique, so it will only ever resolve to zero or one object/value. Thus, you cannot have more than one "base" object, for example, since they resolve to the same thing. Ditto `base.shippingAddress` and `base.shippingAddress.postcode`. Don't different customers have different paths in the tree?

Comment: It would make more sense to think of them as instances. If you think of two object instances (each with their own instance), the property paths (hierarchy) will be identical in both, although the values/instance identifiers (in our case, the id) are different. So if you are talking about instancing `base.shippingAddress.postcode`, every `base` has it's own instance of every possibly path, in order to lead to it's unique value.

Comment: OK @Donny, I still think it is possible. Assuming you are only searching scalar values, start from the other end: find the `address.postcode` column that matches your search value, and note the `id`. Then search the `node` table for `table_name = 'address' AND primary_key=<id>`. From there, use your nested set library to repeatedly find the parent until there is no parent to be had, and you'll be left with a set of node ids that point to this postcode. Since you might have some billing addresses in there, another trivial search will filter them down to shipping addresses.

Comment: the performance issue isn't to do with the ability to find an object, the ORM that I built actually already does this pretty well. The performance problem is in linking the object's property values to it's node, which as we've discovered, can't be done. Because of this, I will still need to fetch all of the objects when I pull the object, regardless of whether this is done with nested sets or not. I explain this here: http://pastie.org/9962144

Comment: Ultimately, performance-wise, i'm pretty much convinced that the nested set formula only helps to increase performance in an area that doesn't really need it's performance increased. When it comes to increasing the performance of actually retrieving an object and all of it's values, nested sets don't really touch this problem in a way that improves performance... (atleast, if I have understood it correctly)

Comment: @Donny, can you synopsise the problem for me? The pastie you supplied is 600 lines long, and I'm having trouble understanding what it is intending to show. Can you make a (really succinct) example that suffers a performance issue?

Comment: (I wonder if this part of your explanation is essentially the problem: _"I didn't want to have to fetch objects, recursively search them on the client in order to find objects based on a condition at any depth of the object"_.)

Comment: I agree that the algorithm I have outlined _might_ not be the solution, but I don't share your confidence that it is definitely not the answer, since either one of us might be missing something! That said, it does feel like the whole thing is getting very complicated, and I wonder whether the core assumptions need to be questioned. Of course, I don't know _why_ objects need to be held in the manner you've described, and maybe there is another way to do what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: So, i've worked away at this over the weekend and essencially the problem is that the nested set nodes cannot be retrieved along with the data (the rows in the model tables). This meant that I would have suffered the same performance problem as before, where every part (object and child objects) would still need to be fetched individually. I have, however, managed to come up with a genius solution that fixes everything, and does tie in with a lot of what you have taught me! It will take some time to fully flesh it out, but when I do I will be sure to share it. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Alright, sounds good @Donny! Pleased to have been of service.

Answer (score 0):

> I am constructing a PHP OOP framework from scratch (I have no choice
>   in this matter)

You always have a choive.

> The framework is required to handle object-oriented data in the most
>   efficient way possible. It doesn't need to be lightning quick, it just
>   needs to be the best possible solution to the problem

I personally would go for serialized strings or ORM+MySQL (InnoDB)

> Objects very closely resemble class instances, in that they are an
>   instance of a specific class, which contains a strict set of
>   properties.

Sounds like definition of... objects. Because object is instance of a class it has to resemble class structure. Also, `class' instance` and `object` is the same thing. So you kinda said `Objects ... resemble objects`.

> Object properties can be basic types (strings, numbers, bools) but can
>   also be one object instance, or an array of objects (with the
>   restriction that the array must be objects of the same type)

Yes, that's purpose of Object-Oriented Programming and one of it's powerful features.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll edit accordingly. You are right to point out that I am referring to the general idea of OOP. The ultimate idea is a storage engine that stores strictly written OOP objects. There definitely exists a whole different type of object, in the form of completely loose and dynamic objects, hence why I felt the need to specify

Comment: My initial en devours were in creating an ORM with the use of mysql. It would be great it you could give some examples of how you suggest I best use this setup, as I have done before and struggled with performance (in particular with largely complex objects). It would also be great to know why you've specified InnoDB